# How can I simplify this piece of jQuery code as much as possible?

Tags: jquery, simplify

I'm looking to simplify this piece of jQuery code as much as possible:

All answers are winners :)

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $("#selectViewport").change(function(){
          if($(this).val() == "1") {
             $('.box').addClass('desktop');
          };
          if($(this).val() == "2") {
             $('.box').addClass('tablet');
          };
          if($(this).val() == "3") {
             $('.box').addClass('mobile');
          };
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You mean something like this:

```
  $("#selectViewport").change(function(){
      const className = {
        '1': 'desktop',
        '2': 'tablet',
        '3': 'mobile'
      }[$(this).val()];

      if (className) 
        $('.box').addClass(className);
    });
```

Comment: Good idea, I like it!